# Can text / snippet to be inserted by Atom autocomplete+ be provided asynchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, autocomplete, atom-editor

I am writing an extension for Atom's autocomplete+ plugin, following the Provider API described at https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/wiki/Provider-API.

The `getSuggestions` function can be implemented asynchronously by returning a promise.

Is it also possible to fetch the `text` or `snippet` to be inserted into the editor after the user selects an autocomplete-entry asynchronously?

In my use case, I want to fetch the `text` to insert into the editor only after the user makes a choice, and not already when fetching (a possibly larger number of) suggestions in `getSuggestions`.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but I think this is doable.

General idea is to let Atom do the suggestion insertion with text as normal (text doesn't matter, can be a placeholder). Then handle `onDidInsertSuggestion()` to immediately undo the insertion. Then use your own Promise to async fetch the actual text and insert it manually. You can use `setTextInBufferRange()` to do this.

I did a similar thing to handle suggestion insertion manually (minus the async part). Maybe this can help you get started: https://github.com/lonekorean/atom-autocomplete-math/blob/master/lib/provider.js#L92

Word of caution, async means there could be a delay between the request for text and the text being inserted. If the user is a fast typer or the internet connection is terrible, weird things might happen.